# Load from source root in PyCharm using different interpreters in same project

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I am using PyCharm professional 2021.2.2, and my project looks like this:

```
My project/
|-- Folder1 
|-- Folder2
|-- ... FolderN
|-- Subproject1
|-- Subproject2
```

The global project `My Project` uses a `python3.10` interpreter, shared with all the folders (1 to N) inside of it. However, inside of this project, I also have 2 sub-projects that have another interpreter (Ubuntu one, for that matter) that I have "attached" to relative folders.

What I am trying to do here is to import in `Subproject1` a set of codes I have in `Folder1`, without any luck so far.
I have also marked `Folder1` as Source root, but somehow it is not detected in Subproject1.

Do you have any ideas about how could I circumvent this problem?

I don't know if I am right, but it is my understanding that when I attached the different interpreters to the folders `SubProject1,2` PyCharm separated them from the main one, and for that reason `Folder1` is not accessible from those.
Anyways, I need to have different working interpreters and import from a common folder, and that was the most convenient solution without having me switch between different projects every time.

Many thanks,

Comment: II have never heard about interpreter `Ubuntu one`. As I remeber there was internet drive `Ubuntu One`. OR maybe you mean standard interpreter installed in Ubuntu. Why do you need to use other interpreter? Better use one interpreter for all code. If you need Ubuntu interpreter then use it for all projects.

Comment: I meant that I have one interpreter for Ubuntu (needed to run some packages) and another one with Windows. Since the one using Ubuntu is via WSL, I am not able to how live plots due to port connection error, and this is why I also have a Windows interpreter.

Comment: you should rather ask for problem with `port connection error` and resolve this problem.